# I think my javascript timers cause the browser to freeze up

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm making a menu with a lot of functionality. I have to implement it towards other developers system, so I haven't been able to successfully make a jsfiddle for it. However, what happens is that if I leave it for a few minutes on the page, and go back to activate it, the browser will freeze for a second or more, perhaps even causing a "This script is causing the page to freeze etc.".

I *think* it's related to my timers. So I was hoping someone could take a look at the functions that run with timers, as my other functions are triggered by mouseevents, and see if they make sense. I know there's a lot of code, but if you specifically look for the timers I think someone with more experience than me can get the jist of it. I'm gonna have to buckle down and see if I get a fiddle to work if not.

The button that triggers the delay itself is the ul.downArrow inside the second timer in the code.

```
/* Check if submenu should be closed */
var timer;
$jq('#subNavigationContainer').hover(
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    },
    function(){
        var checkNavVariation = $jq('#subNavigationContainer').hasClass('small');
        timer=setTimeout(function () {
            if(checkNavVariation == false){
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').animate({
                    height: ['50px', 'easeOutSine']
                }, 600, 'linear');
                var testLevel = $jq('#navigationContainer ul li.pathed').size();
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer ul,#subNavigationContainer #subMenuDescription').fadeOut('fast');  
                setTimeout(function () {
                    /* Indicate we want breadcrumb to open */
                    $jq('#subNavigationContainer').addClass('isClosed');        
                    if(testLevel < 1) {
                        $jq('#navigationContainer ul li').removeClass('selected');      
                    }
                    $jq('#navigationContainer ul li').children('.selArrow').remove();   
                }, 600);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
);

setTimeout(function(){
    $jq('ul.downArrow').click(function() {
        loadMenu();
    }); 
    setTimeout(arguments.callee,1200);
},1200)

/* Automatic check for breadcrumb */
var counter = 0;
setTimeout(function(counter){       
    var subNavVisible = $jq('#subNavigationContainer').css('display');
    var subNavClosed = $jq('#subNavigationContainer').hasClass('isClosed');

    if(subNavClosed == true) {
        if(counter == 0) {
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul').remove();
            $jq('#subNavWrapper div.subMenuDescription').remove();  
        } else {
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul.downArrow').remove();
            $jq('#subNavWrapper div.subMenuDescription').remove();  
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul.levelTwo').remove();     
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul.levelThree').remove();   
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul.levelFour').remove();            

        }
        $jq('#subMenuDescription').remove();
        $jq('#navigationContainer ul.levelOne').children('li.pathed').each(function() {
            /* Mark the top menu */
            $jq(this).siblings('li').removeClass('hover').removeClass('selected');
            $jq(this).siblings('li').children('.selArrow').remove();
            $jq(this).addClass('selected').addClass('hover');
            var liWidth = $jq(this).width();
            liWidth = (liWidth / 2) - 15;
            $jq(this).append('<div class="selArrow" style="margin-left: '+liWidth+'px"></div>');
            var highestHeight = 50;
            $jq(this).children('ul').clone().appendTo('#subNavWrapper').addClass('cloned');             
            $jq(this).children('ul').children('li.selected').children('ul').clone().appendTo('#subNavWrapper').addClass('cloned');
            $jq(this).children('ul').children('li.selected').children('ul').children('li.selected').children('ul').clone().appendTo('#subNavWrapper').addClass('cloned');
            var hasLevel = $jq('#subNavWrapper ul.levelThree li.pathed').size();

            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul').css('display','none');
            /* Check for grey submenu area visible or not */
            var subNavVisible = $jq('#subNavigationContainer').css('display');
            if(subNavVisible != "block") {
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').css('height','0px');
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').css('display','block');
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').addClass('small');
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').animate({
                    height: [highestHeight+'px', 'easeOutSine']
                  }, 300, 'linear');
            } else if(subNavVisible == "block") {
                $jq('#subNavigationContainer').animate({
                    height: [highestHeight+'px', 'easeOutSine']
                  }, 300, 'linear');
            }
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul').css('height','2px').css('width','200px').css('display','block');
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul li').css('display','none');
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul li.pathed').addClass('breadcrumb');
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul li.pathed').fadeIn('fast');
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul li.pathed:last').parent('ul').after('<ul class="downArrow"><li><img src="http://dev.ghostwriter.no/demo/altibox/images/arrow-down.gif" alt="Ekspander" /><span>Utvid meny</span></li></ul>');
            $jq('#subNavWrapper ul').animate({
                height: ['21px', 'easeOutSine']
            }, 100, 'linear');
            counter++;
            $jq('#subNavigationContainer').removeClass('isClosed');
        });
    } else if(subNavClosed == false) {

    }
    setTimeout(arguments.callee,750) 
},750)
```

Comment: You need to use functions to make your code more readable.  You need to store repetitive/complex JQuery selection results in variables.  I suspect your performance problem is due to unintentionally spawned timeouts, resulting in a memory leak, but I don't want to wade in to find out.

Comment: I think you should describe what you want to do as there may be a better alternative using the queue and delay methods instead of timers you have toooo many setTimeout's

Comment: I've been trying to make the code more effective, and will perhaps do more of that, but it's a case of time and shortest way to it working visually I'm afraid. Designer mind, not coder. Val: I'm not familiar with queue and delay tbh. But what is happening essentially is that there are timers checking if the menu is open, if not it will open a breadcrumb like area. Then there's a timer checking for a click on an arrow in the breadcrumb, that will open the menu again. That's what these timers are. I do appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are timers checking if the menu
>   is open, if not it will open a
>   breadcrumb like area

It's better to handle a moment **when** menu is closing and trigger showing your breadcrumb like area. No timeouts required.

> there's a timer checking for a click on an arrow in the breadcrumb, that will open the menu again

Just handle click on an arrow in the breadcrumb and open menu in handler! No timeouts required here.

Comment: The reason I think I started using setTimeout is that I have animations that take a little time to end. But obviously it's much wiser to trigger these functions when the animations end. It's SOOO obvious really. Thanks for giving a hint towards the more sensible option.

Comment: If you need to make some actions with your animations you can use http://api.jquery.com/stop/ with optional parameters: .stop( [clearQueue,] [jumpToEnd] )